# Controlling image movement using scroll bar of browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, scroll, controls

I want to guide an image through a path. The scroll down of browser should bring the image down the path, and the scroll up of browser should make the image to trace back its path.

Here is an example of what I would like to acheive:[image]

I want to guide that bug down the path as the user scrolls down through the article on the page and make it retrace its path when the user scrolls up (The bug's head will always be in the direction of motion).

How can I achieve this using jQuery and javascript?

Comment: Can you describe what you want a little more? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have a picture that describes exactly what i want but this site did not allow me to upload any pic with the question.<coz i'm new & have low reputation> @TrevorSenior

Comment: I have tried using plugins like http://joelb.me/scrollpath/ and all but it dint serve the purpose. I just want to guide an image through a custom zigzag path. Image should trace down the path as we scroll-down & retrace up the path on scroll-up. @JohnKoerner

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow - the restrictions will be lifted soon enough. Link the image in the comments in the meantime (upload to [imgur](http://www.imgur.com/) if you'd like). That's actually a pretty neat plugin there - reading the [docs](https://github.com/JoelBesada/scrollpath) on it now.

Comment: picture that describes my question: http://imgur.com/tPmw5 >I want to guide that bug down the path as the user scrolls down through the article on the page!
and make it retrace its path when the user scrolls up. (bug's head always in the direction of motion) @TrevorSenior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to calculate the path you intend to use, and then bind a function to the scroll event that moves the image based on the distance scrolled, something like :

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
    var S = $(this).scrollTop(),                // scrolled distance
        T = 10 + (S/24),                        // value for Top
        L = 10 + Math.abs(Math.sin(S/400)*50);  // value for Left

    $("img").css({top: T+'%', left: L+'%'});    //set CSS
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8rAqL/2/)

Comment: Thanks a ton! that's exactly what i was looking for! but my path is more of a zigzag type, impossible to write a math equation that defines the path. Is there any other way to define the path?

Comment: Yes, you can write the path as an object or array and use the scroll position as the key to get the values for top/left, but that will take some figuring out aswell, and it would be a long object to cover all the numbers from the top (which is zero) to the bottom (which is usually around 800). Dividing the scrollTop value with the window height etc. will give you values that are relative to the screen size to make it work the same for all screen sizes, it's not really that hard when you get it, so fiddle around a little, log the scrollTop values to the console and see whats going on etc.

Comment: @Nagendra - Oh, and consider accepting the answer if it helps you out, as we do like our reputation points here !

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can directly capture the mouses scroll with javascript or jquery alone. As that works with whats part of the browser, and inside the "window". You can however capture a scroll event. Based on the windows height/width. It takes a little calculation via javascript to build a reliable/stable equation that will work on all browsers in all resolutions. I'm not going to go into details here more so due to the fact that your question is rather vague and doesn't supply a problem to be solved more than it sounds like a demand for an answer.

But the essence of what you may want to do is, get the width/height of the window/body. And through some trickery of smoke and mirrors or in this case HTML and CSS and properly laying out a bunch of layers on top of one another create a page thats a mile long, with a hidden scroll bar, that you have 2 layers on top of one acting as your "path" and the other your image.. Of which when scrolled from point a to point b is tracked via the scrolling event of the page being a mile long under it all. And then use that couples with the width/height found to make adjustments so it doesnt run off screen at any given point (less thats what you want).